# ZipFile is not declared in Visual basic 2017

Tags: visual-studio, zip

I'm trying to make a little test app to compress and extract folders, and here is my code :

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Compression

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog()
        If Not FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath = "" Then
            Dim startPath As String = FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath
            Dim zipPath As String = "C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\result.zip"
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

And the error is in the `ZipFile` command :

> **ZipFile** is not declared. it may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

I'v searched a lot, and my target framework is 4.5.2 so Zip file should be supported, and i'm using visual studio 2017.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Read the `Important` note [at the top of the FM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @HansPassant , I added `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` but it says that : [Screenshot](http://imgur.com/a/t92kk)

Comment: That is not what the FM told you to do.  Google "vb.net how to add an assembly reference" to learn how to do it correctly.

Comment: Okay, i know how to add a Reference, but i don't know what is the Reference that i suppose to add. ist a dll file or what?

Comment: Thanks, i did it and it worked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved the problem with adding a reference, just go to **`Project`** tab --> **`Add Reference`** --> **`Assemblies`** tab and then select **`System.IO.Compression.FileSystem`** and add it, and it should work, here is some images too :

[image]
[image]

Hope someone will find this useful.

Answer (score 3):

This may not affect everyone, but this is what I had to do to solve this issue (leaving this here as a self-note as much as anything).

I ended up having to find System.IO.Compression.dll, System.IO.Compression.Filesystem.DLL, and System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll on my computer and move them to the BIN folder of the site I'm working on. As soon as I did so, any "not declared" errors disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem as the initial question. I followed the other solutions/comments above and ended up with having to do the following which has slight variations to the details:

- Add `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` to the Assembly references
- Add both the below imports code lines to the beginning of the code:

  ```
  Imports System.IO '(Needed for additional file system functions used)
  Imports System.IO.Compression.ZipFile
  ```
- Calling function without preceeding "ZipFile.":

  ```
  CreateFromDirectory(FileLocation1 & "\", FileLocation1 & ".zip")
  ```

I hope this may support others facing the same issue.

BR
Fnk